# Print all the information based from the separator

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

I have an output file that looks like.

```
Id Name            Persona       -WWN/iSCSI_Name- Port
73 GLOB-A2-WST2   WindowsServer 5001438036830FDE 0:2:4
                                 5001438036830FDC 0:2:3
                                 5001438036830FDE 1:2:4
                                 5001438036830FDC 1:2:3
74 GLOB-A2-WST3   WindowsServer 5001438036830FEE 0:2:2
                                 5001438036830FEC 1:2:1
                                 5001438036830FEC 0:2:1
                                 5001438036830FEE 1:2:2
56 GLOBBACDB01      Generic       50014380073051CC ---
                                 50014380073051CE ---
64 GLOBCIBSSLRDB01  Generic-ALUA  5001438024D29646 0:2:2
                                 5001438024D29644 1:2:1
                                 5001438024D29644 0:2:1
                                 5001438024D29646 1:2:2
65 GLOBCIBSSLRDB02  Generic-ALUA  5001438024D293C6 0:2:4
                                 5001438024D293C4 1:2:3
                                 5001438024D293C4 0:2:3
                                 5001438024D293C6 1:2:4
57 GLOBCRMDB01      WindowsServer 5001438026EDA668 ---
                                 5001438026EDA66A ---
44 GLOBETEBPIDB01   WindowsServer 50014380296B9B86 1:2:4
37 GLOBVMWBCKHS01   WindowsServer 10000090FA371A09 1:2:4
                                 10000090FA371A08 1:2:3
                                 10000090FA371A08 0:2:3
                                 10000090FA371A09 0:2:4
17 S5POC           Generic-ALUA  21000024FF4D665E 1:2:4
                                 21000024FF4D6660 1:2:3
                                 21000024FF4D6660 0:2:3
                                 21000024FF4D665E 0:2:4
34 SOXICS50        Generic       210100E08BB0EE80 ---
                                 210100E08BB2C145 ---
                                 10000000C94A7EC7 ---
                                 210000E08B92C145 ---
59 UNISI279        AIX-legacy    10000000C944BBF0 ---
                                 10000000C944C29F ---
55 VMX01          VMware        10000000C9D09728 ---
                                 10000000C9D09ADC ---
58 VMX02          VMware        10000000C9D0AC2B ---
                                 10000000C9D0AC27 ---
```

if i tried to grep, for example GLOBCIBSSLRDB01,

my output will just print the line it is associated.

```
$ cat p | grep -i GLOBCIBSSLRDB01
64 GLOBCIBSSLRDB01  Generic-ALUA  5001438024D29646 0:2:2
```

**How can I make it appear to include all the information about the host that looks like this.**

```
Name of the file where the host is found 
64 GLOBCIBSSLRDB01  Generic-ALUA     5001438024D29646 0:2:2
                                     5001438024D29644 1:2:1
                                     5001438024D29644 0:2:1
                                     5001438024D29646 1:2:2
echo (space)

Name of the file where the host is found 
64 GLOBCIBSSLRDB01  Generic-ALUA     5001438024D29646 0:2:2
                                     5001438024D29644 1:2:1
                                     5001438024D29644 0:2:1
                                     5001438024D29646 1:2:2
```

where the name of the file is the **switch name** because I redirected the output to temp file naming per switch using for loop.

so each time the host is found on the file, then it will print like the above :)

Comment: Just to be clear, you want it to effectively print everything from the previous/current ID to the not-include next ID?

Comment: @gafm, By seeing your profile came to know that you don't select an answer as correct answer, so give it sometime and when you have some answers try to select any of them as correct answer. You could do it for all previous questions too(in case you found your answer in them too).

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, sorry my bad. Will review all my post and select an answer. sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please give Awk a shot. The following should be POSIX compliant.

```
read -p "Match: " match
awk -v IGNORECASE=1 -v m="$match" '$2~m {p=1} NF>2 && $2!~m {p=0} p' file
```

- `$2~m {p=1}` - if second field matches `m`, set `p` to 1
- `NF>2 && $2!~m {p=0}` - If there are more than two fields and the second does not match `m`, set `p` to 0
- `p` - If p is non-zero, print the line, otherwise do nothing

Comment: good catch @vintnes. hurray! However, i have a problem searching for another host. Is there a way to ignore the case distinction like in `grep -i`?

Comment: @gafm Please see updated script for case insensitivity; using regex match you can also specify GLOB-A2-WST at the prompt and it would match 2 and 3. Everyone who volunteers their time here would appreciate it if you read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Thanks @vintnes. Added the IGNORECASE and it's working fine now. Thank you so much for you help. `awk -v m=$host 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE = 1} $2==m {p=1} NF>2 && $2!=m {p=0} p' ${temp}/*`

Comment: Hi vintnes, so i was able to display the host and ignore the case distinction. Thanks to your help. However, the name of the file where the host/string is found is not printed. How can i do that as well? i edited my OP. can you check please.

Comment: @gafm That should probably be a separate question. I'll give you two hints. The current file name is stored in a special variable `FILENAME`, and you can separate commands in an `{action}` with a semicolon `;`. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with `awk`, could you please try following.

```
awk -v string="GLOBCIBSSLRDB01" '!/^ +/{flag=""} $2==string{flag=1} flag' Input_file
```

You could change value of string `-v string="GLOBCIBSSLRDB01"` in above code for different string search. Also code is comparing it with 2nd field of lines(in case it is different field) then you could change it.

Output will be as follows.

```
64 GLOBCIBSSLRDB01  Generic-ALUA  5001438024D29646 0:2:2
                                 5001438024D29644 1:2:1
                                 5001438024D29644 0:2:1
                                 5001438024D29646 1:2:2
```

Taking inspiration from @vintnes and changing code to look for multiple hosts as per  OP's comments(haven't tested it).

```
awk -v hosts="globcibsslrdb01,xyz,abc" '
BEGIN{
  split(hosts,array,",")
}
{
  val=tolower($2)
}
(val in a){
  flag=val
  p=1
}
NF>2 && val!=flag{
  p=0
}
p
'  Input_file
```

Comment: tried it and it doesn't print all the info i want. Like vintnes said, the data section is dynamic.

Comment: @gafm, I just added output which I am getting after running code and it looks to be same as shown by you, please be more clear for expected output?

Comment: basically, this portion can be less or more than 4 `5001438024D29646 0:2:2
5001438024D29644 1:2:1
5001438024D29644 0:2:1
5001438024D29646 1:2:2`. What i want to capture is the information about the host whether that iscsi are is less or more.

Comment: @gafm, It will definitely print all lines till a line a comes which is NOT starting from space, so it is NOT hard coded to print 4 lines after match, kindly do let me know in case of any queries here?

Comment: by the way i have an input option to search for host.. `read host`.. when i changed the host to search, it doesn't print all the `-WWN/iSCSI_Name-` that has more that 4 data

Comment: @gafm, solutions will be provided as per samples and OP only, I am really confuse now, this was not mentioned in your question. Please provide more details in your question itself and let me know then.

Comment: sorry i'm not allowed for chat due to low points. but this code from vintnes works `awk -v m=GLOBCIBSSLRDB01 '$2==m {p=1} NF>2 && $2!=m {p=0} p' file`. However, how can i search for another host that ignores case distinction?

Comment: @gafm, please check my edit solution(end of this post) and let me know if that helps you?

Comment: Didn't work. However, I got it working. Edited vintnes code and add some ignorecase.. Here it is `awk -v m=$host 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE = 1} $2==m {p=1} NF>2 && $2!=m {p=0} p' ${temp}/*`.. Thank you guys for being patient. :)

Comment: @gafm, my solution will work when you are passing many hosts as variable of `awk` please note that, you need not to run loop and run `awk` each time. You could ask user to run script and pass all jhosts names(may be) as arguments etc(just a suggestion) in that case you can save time too.